# Adding more than one GET value in the href

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, get

I got this HTML with several unordered lists.

```
<ul>
    <h3>Staff</h3>
    <li><a href="?staff=Mike">Mike</a></li>
    <li><a href="?staff=John">John</a></li>
    <li><a href="?staff=Kyle">Kyle</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <h3>Category</h3>
    <li><a href="?category=Food">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Sports">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=News">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Games">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=GIFs">GIFs</a></li>
</ul>
```

As can be seen, all of them contains  with params values in each of its hrefs. My question is: using Javascript, how can I append a new value in a param in the href if one of them are actives in the URL.

IE:
The URL is [www.site.com/?category=Food](http://www.site.com/?category=Food).

So the lists should be valued as:

```
<ul>
    <h3>Staff</h3>
    <li><a href="?category=Food&staff=Mike">Mike</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Food&staff=John">John</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Food&staff=Kyle">Kyle</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <h3>Category</h3>
    <li><a href="?category=Food">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Food,Sports">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Food,News">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Food,Games">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Food,GIFs">GIFs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you desire? I didn't understand your example.

Comment: I have a website www.site.com. I made a click in the option Food. Them the URL became www.site.com/?category=Food. Right? Next, if window.location.search is true, the `<ul>` should have in its `<a>` its own value + the active search param in the URL.

Comment: @Cario so, you want additional query parameters to be appended on to the end of the url, without removing the ones that are already there.

Comment: I'm sorry. My bad. I made the fixes. Staffs belong to staffs and Category to categories. Sure, I want to add parameters in addition to those who is already query in the URL.

Comment: So if a query param already exists in the link, the value from the URL is added via CSV (comma-separate value)? Is it only `category` you expect in the page URL or can anything appear there that should be added to the links?

Comment: Sure, it can be comma or plus sign (+). Same thing for, another example: if I select Mike, the URL will become `www.site.com.br/?staff=Mike`. Next, If I want to select Games, URL will become `www.site.com.br/?staff=Mike&category=Games`. Finally, if I select Kyle, URL should be `www.site.com.br/?staff=Mike,Kyle&category=Games`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is

1. Parse the current query string into an `URLSearchParams` object
2. For each `<a>` element, parse the `href` into an `URL` object
3. Iterate the query params from step #1 and...

   1. Check if the param already exists
   2. If it does not, simply append it
   3. If it does, then parse the current *list* into a `Set`, add the value from the query string, then write the value back into the `URL`
4. Write the `URL` into the `<a>` `href` property

```js
//const query = location.search
const query = "?category=Food" // this is for the snippet

// Parse any CSV values into arrays and store in a `Map`
const params = new Map()
for (let [ key, val ] of (new URLSearchParams(query))) {
  params.set(key, val.split(","))
}

const links = document.querySelectorAll("ul li a[href]")

links.forEach(link => {
  const url = new URL(link.href)
  
  // Loop the page query params
  for (let [ param, values ] of params) {
    if (url.searchParams.has(param)) {
      // Split the current value on "," and parse to a `Set`
      const linkParams = new Set(url.searchParams.get(param).split(","))
      
      // Add the query string value then write the param back into the URL
      values.forEach(v => linkParams.add(v))
            
      url.searchParams.set(param, [...linkParams].join(","))
    } else {
      // Simply append the param value 
      url.searchParams.append(param, values.join(","))
    }
  }
  link.href = url
})
```

```css
/* This just makes it easy to see the URLs in the demo */
a[href]:after {
  content: " - " attr(href);
  font-size: .8;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <h3>Staff</h3>
    <li><a href="?staff=Mike">Mike</a></li>
    <li><a href="?staff=John">John</a></li>
    <li><a href="?staff=Kyle">Kyle</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <h3>Category</h3>
    <li><a href="?category=Food">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Sports">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=News">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=Games">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="?category=GIFs">GIFs</a></li>
</ul>
```